# How to fix angular deprecate whitelistedNonPeerDependencies in favor of allowedNonPeerDependencies

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I got the following warning in my cli and was wondering what was the new `allowedNonPeerDependencies` doing different.

```
WARNING: Option "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies" is deprecated: Use "allowedNonPeerDependencies" instead.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically we should only rename `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies` into `allowedNonPeerDependencies` into the `package.json` and `ng-package.json` files.

As said [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1884) it is to be "less racially charged" so nothing else to changes in the code.